# Easy way to find Frost Crystal or Frostwort?

Tags: no-mans-sky

For a quest I need some [Frost Crystals](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Frost_Crystal) **.
As far is I know, they grow at the top of a tree called [Frostwort](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Frostwort#Game_description).

Do you know any easy way to find such Frost Crystals or the Frostwort trees?

** *I know how to refine them, I'm looking for a solution to find them in the wild.*

Answer (score 4):

According to [this guide](https://www.gameskinny.com/ya16b/no-mans-sky-where-to-find-frost-crystals) (and some personal experience), Frostworts/Frost Crystals can be found on

- Cold, icy planets planets
- Moons that are black, blue, and purple in color.

Once you find them, you will need the [Haz-Mat Gauntlet](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Haz-Mat_Gauntlet) in order to harvest the resources. If you are having trouble locating them on the planet, [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoMansSkyTheGame/comments/96gpbd/lets_talk_frostwort_and_frost_crystal/e40add4) recommends waiting until nightfall. Because the tip of the Frostwort glows, they will be easier to find when it's dark

Comment: i'm actually on a ice cold planet (> -100° Celsius, Frost Crystal is one of the listed resource) but after more then 1 hour of manual search (fly over the surface) I can't find them...

Comment: @PeterCo That happens to me from time to time with other resources. Whenever that happened, I would generically find some after flying to another location a good distance away. Give that a go

Answer (score 4):

(I would include this in a comment, but I'm unable to do that given my current reputation.)

To build off of the previous answer above, even if you don't have the Haz-Mat Gauntlet, there are some flora whose secondary element is Frost Crystal. It can be a bit slow-going, but you can farm these plants/trees until you have the desired amount (as long as you're on one of the planets specified above).